# After tests chrome process remains Laravel Dusk in a Docker container

Tags: laravel, selenium, docker, phpunit, laravel-dusk

After running Dusk tests with **Atlassian Bamboo**, Chrome process remains as "zombies".

Bellow my driver code initialization:

```php
$options = (new ChromeOptions())
           ->addArguments(['--disable-gpu', '--headless', '--no-sandbox', ]);

$chrome = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()
          ->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY,$options)
          ->setCapability('acceptInsecureCerts', true);

return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $chrome);
```

My `composer.json`:

```
"require-dev":{
   "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper":"^2.5",
   "filp/whoops":"^2.0",
   "fzaninotto/faker":"^1.4",
   "laravel/dusk":"^4.0",
   "mockery/mockery":"^1.0",
   "nunomaduro/collision":"^2.0",
   "phpunit/phpunit":"^7.0",
   "squizlabs/php_codesniffer":"3.*"
}
```

Bellow a screenshot to prove zombies processes:

**Result of top command:**

[image: Result of top command]

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging, it seems that the cause was a missing flag on a Docker container:

You **MUST** append to your `docker run` the flag `--init`

From the official Atlassian documentation:
[atlassian/bamboo-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/bamboo-server/)

> Note that the --init flag is required to properly reap zombie processes.